# Batch push notification on Batch.onStart(this)

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I use batch.com for push notification service, and i got error when initializing it.
this my activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Batch.onStart(this);
}
```

}

i got this error when activity launch :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.negin.batch_test, PID: 687
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.batch.android.BatchPushInstanceIDService
```

this is my gradle :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.batch.android:batch-sdk:1.10+'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support of batch.com was very great,
they help me to solve the bug by replacing google play services with this :

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
```